# How to add data (Jtable data actually) into database. Is there any way to insert an object into database using preparedstmt?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, jtable

```
public cntctus() 
{
```

column names for `JTable`

```
    String column[]= { "Name","Position","Phone"};
```

rows for `JTable`

```
    Object [][]row = {
            {"Prof. Renu Vig", "Director", "+123456"},
            {"Mr. Sukhbir singh", "Assistant Professor", "+9123568989"},
            {"Ms. shaweta", "BI teacher","9468645"}
    };


    table = new JTable(row,column);
    TableModel tm = table.getModel();
    java.sql.Connection con=null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/training","root","");
     try{
         java.sql.Statement stmt =con.createStatement();
String maketable = "CREATE TABLE if not exists contacttable(Name Varchar(25),Position Varchar(20),Phone Varchar(20))";
         stmt.executeUpdate(maketable);
        System.out.print("table created ");
//insert into table contacttable query 

PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("INSERT into contacttable select     distinct    values(?,?,?)");
```

get some `TableModel` that will contain the data

```
        for (int i = 0; i < tm.getRowCount(); i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < tm.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            Object o = tm.getValueAt(i, j);


 System.out.println("object from table is  : " +o);
 k=j+1;          
 pstmt.setString(k, (String)o);
  }
 pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }

      }
     catch(SQLException s)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
     catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

I want to insert this whole object into database.in short how to insert jtable data into databse.?? please help.

error is: **you have an error in your sql syntax at line 1 ('"prof. renu vig, "director"...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event that you want to have multiple rows on your prepared statement, you could just take what you have now and add a call to pstmt.addBatch() inside the outer loop, and outside the inner loop (the loops which iterate over the JTable, IE add batch once per row). Then after you have iterated over the whole table call pstmt.executeBatch().

A word to the wise though, if you are generating keys on insert, the drivers must also support returning multiple keys on batch inserts, or you will probably just get the first key generated back instead of all of them. Alternatively you could execute the statement each iteration of the outer loop (IE once per row), making sure to call .clearParamters() after each execution. You will want to reuse the preparedStatement for performance reasons.

Your insert statement is also screwed up. Its just going to be INSERT INTO contacttable VALUES(?,?,?). Get rid of the select distinct stuff.

It will probably look like this when its done:

```
    String column[]= { "Name","Position","Phone"};
    Object [][]row = {
            {"Prof. Renu Vig", "Director", "+123456"},
            {"Mr. Sukhbir singh", "Assistant Professor", "+9123568989"},
            {"Ms. shaweta", "BI teacher","9468645"}
    };

    JTable table = new JTable(row,column);
    TableModel tm = table.getModel();
    java.sql.Connection con=null;
    try
    {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/training","root","");

        java.sql.Statement stmt =con.createStatement();
        String maketable = "CREATE TABLE if not exists contacttable(Name Varchar(25),Position Varchar(20),Phone Varchar(20))";
        stmt.executeUpdate(maketable);
        System.out.print("table created ");

        PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO contacttable VALUES(?,?,?)");

        for (int i = 0; i < tm.getRowCount(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tm.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                Object o = tm.getValueAt(i, j);
                System.out.println("object from table is  : " +o);
                pstmt.setString(j+1, (String)o);
            }
             pstmt.executeUpdate();
             pstmt.clearParameters();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: okay. let me explain the changes i have done on my code  :-
     /* get some table-model that will contain the data */
   
   for (int i = 0; i <tm.getRowCount(); i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j <tm.getColumnCount(); j++) {
      Object  o =  tm.getValueAt(i, j);
       System.out.println("object from table is  : " +o);
       
     pstmt.setString(k,(String) o);
    
    }
     pstmt.addBatch();
     }
   pstmt.executeBatch();     
   
   }
 still I am getting some errors like :-parameter index out of range. 
and sysout is printing only PROF.RENU VIG..
i WANT TO INSERT WHOLE TABLE DATABASE.

Comment: Its really hard to see your edits in a comment, if you could put them in the OP that would be great.

Comment: perfect!! You helped me a lot. @Mark W 
but i want to stop this data entering again and again in database. (that is why i used SELECT DISTINCT.) but select distinct query is not working. Any suggestions to stop reinsertion of JTable data into database??

Comment: I had written out a couple of suggestions for this here, but decided to remove them. The topic of data integrity and validation is too broad a topic for me to just spit out a one size fits all answer. Long story short, you should be using integrity constraints on your DB to ensure no duplicates get inserted DB side, as well as performing validation in your business logic application side so that you can do what you feel is appropriate to notify the user of duplicate records.

Comment: ohk ohk. I got it. I am going to change database constraints now. thanks a lot @Mark.

Answer (score 0):

The Only one change You have to do with your Code i.e

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tm.getRowCount(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tm.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            Object o = tm.getValueAt(i, j);
            System.out.println("object from table is  : " +o);
            pstmt.setObject(j+1, o);
```

it will send your actual JTable data into your Database file.
i am sure. it will work work.

Answer (score -1):

***i have an exemple with jpa i hope that it help you***

try{

```
          TableModel tm= table.getModel();

                  for (int i = 0; i < tm.getRowCount(); i++) {



                    Object  NumeroCin=tm.getValueAt(i, 0);
                    Object  Nomprenom=tm.getValueAt(i, 1);
                    Object  Tel =tm.getValueAt(i, 2);
                    Object  Adresse =tm.getValueAt(i, 3);
                    Object  DateNaissance=tm.getValueAt(i, 5);
                    Object  Sexe=tm.getValueAt(i, 4);



                    Etudiant e=new Etudiant();
                e.setAdresse((String) Adresse);
                e.setDateNaissance((String) DateNaissance);
                e.setNomprenom((String) Nomprenom);
                e.setNumeroCin((String) NumeroCin);
                e.setSexe( (String) Sexe );
                e.setTel((String) Tel);

                Ajouterobjet(e);

                }}}

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

public void Ajouterobjet(Object o)
     {

```
     EntityTransaction tx=entityManager.getTransaction();
     tx.begin();
     entityManager.persist(o);
     tx.commit();


 }
```